# Verbatim environment to split long words over lines

Tags: listings, verbatim, code

After some reading I thought the listings package would be able to handle this, but I'm not having any success. I have some longish code strings that I need to include in the paragraphs of the document, and I want these to break over lines, or to simply leave white space and put on a new line, as needed. Currently, I can only convince the listings package to line break when there is a space in the code string.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{breaklines=true}
\begin{document}
\verb|lllllllllllllllllllllloooooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnggggggg$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$llllllllllllloooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnngggggggg$$$$$$$|

\lstinline|lllllllllllllllllllllloooooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnggggggg$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$llllllllllllloooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnngggggggg$$$$$$$|

\lstinline|lllllllllllllllllllllloooooooooooooooooonnnn nnnnnnnnnggggggg$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$llllllllllllloooooooooooooooonnnnnnnn nnnnnnnngggggggg$$$$$$$|
\end{document}
```

Comment: If your code is not from a file you might give `\texttt{}` a shot (though it doesn't handle stuff like `$` and the like).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

You can iterate through the verb, adding a breakpoint after each character.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\old@sverb\@sverb
\def\@sverb#1{\old@sverb{#1}\zz}
\def\zz#1{#1\ifx\@undefined#1\else\penalty\z@\expandafter\zz\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\raggedright

\verb|lllllllllllllllllllllloooooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnggggggg$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$llllllllllllloooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnngggggggg$$$$$$$|

\verb|`?<<---|

\verb|`?<<---ooooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnggggggg$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$llllllllllllloooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnngggggggg$$$$$$$|

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. This also works fine once I include all my other formatting packages, verbatim in footnotes etc.

Answer (score 4):

A solution with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\splitverb}{v}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \use:c { verbatim@font }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {} {#1}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \hspace{0pt plus .2em}\penalty\c_zero\hspace{0pt plus -.2em} }
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Some text \splitverb|lllllllllllllllllllllloooooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnggggggg$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$llllllllllllloooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnngggggggg$$$$$$$|

Let's see that ligatures are not formed: \splitverb|`?<<---|

\end{document}
```

The combination of `\hspace` and `\penalty` ensures you don't get overfull boxes.

[image]

You may want to add some glue with small flexibility instead.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\splitverb}{v}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \use:c { verbatim@font }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {} {#1}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \hspace{0pt plus 0.1pt} }
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Some text \splitverb|lllllllllllllllllllllloooooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnggggggg$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$llllllllllllloooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnngggggggg$$$$$$$|

Let's see that ligatures are not formed: \splitverb|`?<<---|

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Problems arose with this once I included it in my full document, so I accepted the seemingly more robust (in terms of package / formatting interactions) approach from David Carlisle.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a macro that typesets each character on its own using `\string`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\mycode|#1#2|{%
    \texttt{\string#1}\penalty\z@%
    \ifx&#2&%
    \else%
        \mycode|#2|%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mycode|lllllllllllllllllllllloooooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnggggggg$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$llllllllllllloooooooooooooooonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnngggggggg$$$$$$$|
\end{document}
```

But David Carlisle's answer might be better.

Comment: if I add that definition to the test file it runs without error but it adds a space between each character and typesets `|` (as an em-dash in OT1 encoding) at the end)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I saw that, too (just after posting the answer). Do you know where this behavior originates from?

Comment: yes the space is the missing `%` after the `{` (although you do not add any break point apart from that) and the final `|` is because you typeset `#1` _before_ testing if you are at the end. (also why do you not put the definition in the test file so people can run your answer?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I found the issues myself but thanks for the explanations and effort. I'll edit the answer again to include the `\def` in the document.